# Global BCC for all Emails from Joomla

Tags: joomla-3.x, emails

Is there a way to for Joomla to add a BCC to all emails it sends?

I am using the contacts component with over 160 contacts that are contactable via the contact form option. I want to be able to add a BCC to all emails sent via this option.

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do this from Joomla as there are no events triggered when a mail is sent (hopefully this will change in the future).

Now, if you're into core modifications, then you can do this through a core modification. Just open the file `components/com_contact/controllers/contact.php` and add the following line just below `$mail->addRecipient($contact->email_to);`

```
$mail->addBcc('youremail@yourdomain.com');
```

Comment: itoctopus: can you make a Pull Request at [Github](https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms)?